Was Mars hit by a one billion megatons air-burst thermonuclear explosion (over Mars Acidalium) in its past?
There's an intriguing academic presentation claiming in the end that

Yield ~ 1 billion megatons [...]
Evidence for Mars paleo-nuclear event is
strong- but no crater at ground zero

Natural nuclear reactor explosion would
have created a large deep crater

Absence of crater suggests Air Burst after
ocean dried up


The weapon exploded over Mars Acidalium after
ocean was dried up, throwing debris globally and
releasing large amounts of Xenon while a U-Th
rich debris layer irradiated the surface by delayed
neutrons.

The presentation doesn't merely discuss some kind of large impact, in equivalent thermonuclear yield, but rather claims there are fallout products compatible with such weapons. Essentially, it seems to claim there's a thorium hotspot over Mare Acidalium, accompanied by "“Trinitite” Glass".
It also does not claim this was a weapon necessarily made by an intelligent species, but discusses the possibility that it may have been a nature-made reactor/weapon:

Asteroid hosted natural nuclear reactor.

I'm guessing all this is somewhat controversial (given that we've not seen such "natural nuclear reactor[s]" on asteroids much?--N.B. I'm aware of a 'natural nuclear reactor' being discussed on earth. I'm not sure if that's the same kind that would be needed to set off the putative event here.) Are there alternative theories for those observations of tritium etc. on Mars?

Slightly more googling (for those who hate slide-based claims) found a 2-page paper https://www.lpi.usra.edu/meetings/lpsc2011/pdf/1097.pdf from the same autor. This (unlike the slides) makes explicit ref to the Oklo 'natural reactor' on Earth, as relevant. Unlike the slides, this claims the reactor that initiated the event was actually on Mars.

Looks like it made it to the popsci pages as well https://www.foxnews.com/science/was-there-a-natural-nuclear-blast-on-mars

I haven't found enough to answer, but according to RationalWiki, the author "went off the rails" in 2012, and his papers have not been peer reviewed. I don't have enough time to look further but maybe this will help someone interested to do so. https://rationalwiki.org/wiki/John_Brandenburg

Also following the RationalWiki link, you can get here, where the author has made several comments. https://scienceblogs.com/pharyngula/2014/11/22/the-two-faces-of-je-brandenburg

@JeromeViveiros: interesting.  I had no idea. Not sure why the Q was DV. I ran into his presentation while searching for answers to another Q. Has pretty high google juice and the Fox News coverage should make it notable enough.

Not my DV. I think it's notable enough. And reading his comments is quite fascinating. Amazing that a smart man can go so horribly wrong though.

@JeromeViveiros Such people in the academic fields are called "cranks" and they are unfortunately more common than you'd think.
